# HTML/Javascript- Adding user input as an JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, json, url

I'm trying to add my user input as an JSON object to a localHost website. This is my HTML page. When user clicks on "Add Service", the button should add the information as an JSON object.

HTML Page.

```
<table style="width:100%" id= "intake">
<tr><td>
  <label for="firstName">First Name: </label></td><td>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" v-model="firstName"></td> </tr>
<tr><td>
 <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label></td><td>
  <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" v-model="lastName"></td> </tr>
<tr><td>
<label for="member">Member Number:</label></td><td>
  <input type="number" name="member" id="member" v-model="member" min= "1"> </td> </tr>
<tr><td>
<label for="ticket">Ticket Number:</label></td><td>
  <input type="number" name="ticket" id="ticket" v-model="ticket" min= "1"> </td> </tr>
<tr><td>
<label for="phone">Phone Number:</label> </td><td>
  <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" v-model="phone" min= "1">  </td> </tr>
<tr><td>
<label for="email">Email:</label> </td><td>
 <input type="email" name="email" id="email" v-model="email" > </td> </tr>
 <tr><td>
 <label for="services">Service:</label> </td><td>
    <select name="services" id="services" v-model="services">
      <option value = "0">Options...</option>
      <option value = "1">Bronze Tune</option>
      <option value = "2">Silver Tune</option>
      <option value = "3">Gold Tune</option>
      <option value = "4">Bronze Wax</option>
      <option value = "5">Silver Wax</option>
      <option value = "6">Wax</option>
    </select> </td> </tr>
 <tr><td>
 <label for="notificationPreference">Notification Preference</label> </td><td>
    <select name="notification" id="notification" v-model="notification">
      <option value = "0">Options...</option>
      <option value = "1">1</option>
      <option value = "2">2</option>
      <option value = "3">3</option>
    </select> </td> </tr>
<tr><td>
<button class = "button5" id="add_service">Add Service</button>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<label for="notes">Notes:</label> </td><td>
<textarea type="notes" name="notes" id="notes" v-model="notes" input style="height:200px"></textarea> </td> </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

Not all of these options will be added; Only first name, last name, phone num, email, and notification pref is added atm.

This is the JS script I had to add it.

```
function addCustomer() {    
    document.getElementById('add_service').onclick = function() {      
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
        var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
        var phoneNum = document.getElementById("phone").value;
        var emailAddress = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var notifications = document.getElementById("notification").value;

        request.open('GET', url, true);

        request.onload = function () {
            var url = 'localhost:8080/customer/add?
                firstName='firstName'
                &lastName='lastName'
                &custPhone='phoneNum'
                &custEmail='emailAddress'
                &notificationPreference='notifications;
        }
        request.send();
    }​;​
}
```

What this JS script does is- If user clicks "Add services", it should add this information to the JSON object.

This is the URL that, when user input is appended to it, will add it as an object.

```
localhost:8080/customer/add?firstName=STRING&lastName=STRING&custPhone=STRING&custEmail=STRING&notificationPreference=INTEGER
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I appending the user input wrong onto the URL, or miscoded the button click?

**EDIT:** ADDED JSON OBJECT Example

```
{
    "custID": 100501,
    "custEmail": "test1@test1.net",
    "custPhone": "1115552222",
    "firstName": "TestFirst1",
    "lastName": "TestLast1",
    "notificationPreference": 2
},
```

Comment: "it should add this information to the JSON object." - what JSON object you are referring to?

Comment: as above, there is no JSON at all even hinted at in your code

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I added the JSON object now!

Comment: @JaromandaX as well

Comment: What are you trying to implement/achieve? What problem do you face?

Comment: how does that random JSON object relate to anything? (hint: it doesn't seem to at all)

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I'm trying to add user input as an JSON object. So, I have a list of JSON objects stored in a localhost URL- this is customer information. What am I doing now is, for new customers, I'm trying to add those as JSON objects as well. The localhost URL I specified will add customer details as an JSON object (I verified this by adding fake customer data directly). What I want to do now is, take user input from a HTML page, and add that as an JSON object

Comment: @JaromandaX It's just an example of how the JSON object looks like. This is what I want to create, when a new customer registeres their info, their info should be stored as an JSON object like this. But my website isn't sending the information atm

Answer (score 0):

One issue I am seeing here is a wrong concat in the url. You are missing the '+' operator. This works:

```
var firstName = 'Max';

var url = 'localhost:8080/customer/add?firstName=' + firstName + '&lastName=';
console.log(url);
```